# Smallest divisible repunits

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

A repunit of length k is a number containing k ones (1, 11, 111...).

R(k) is defined to be the repunit of length k.

A(n) is the least value of k such that R(k) is divisble by n (assuming gcd(n, 10) = 1).

Reading online, several articles claim that A(n) < n, but no explanation is given (and that's why I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious...), and I don't understand how that inequality came to be.
An explanation on why that inequality holds would be very appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't assume that people here will know what's a "repunit"

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't mention that this has to do with proj euler at all, because now people searching google for "proj euler NNN" will find this. (and folks at projecteuler dot net ask you specifically not to do this)

Comment: You are right, I removed references to that place. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $\gcd(10,n)=1$, then by the Euler-Fermat theorem we have $$10^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$$

Therefore 
$$10^{\phi(n)}-1 \equiv 0 \mod n$$

$$n \mid 10^{\varphi(n)}-1$$

Therefore 
$$n \mid \underbrace{999...999}_{\varphi(n)}$$
$$n \mid R(\varphi(n))$$

And for $n>1$ we have $\varphi(n) < n$.

Comment: You can say $n\mid 9R(\phi(n))$, but not $n\mid R(\phi(n))$, unless $\gcd(n,3)=1$ (as Syd Henderson notes).

Comment: Together with Barry/Syd's comment, I understand now :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It's also not true for powers of 3.

Answer (score 1):

The correct claim is $A(n)\le n$, which can be proved by the pigeonhole principle.  The set of $n$ numbers $\{1,11,111,\ldots,111...11\}$ either exhausts the remainders mod $n$, in which case the one with remainder $0$ is divisible by $n$, or else, by the pigeonhole principle, two of them have the same remainder, in which case their difference is divisible by $n$.  But the difference of two repunits is of the form $111\ldots11000\ldots00$, at which point one invokes the assumption $\gcd(n,10)=1$ to conclude that $n$ divides the opening repunit in that difference.